# Do Romanian nouns use the same gender as corresponding Latin nouns?

Tags: grammar, grammatical-gender, latin, romanian

Both [Latin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latin_grammar#Gender) and [Romanian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Romanian_grammar#Gender) have three noun genders - masculine, feminine, neuter. What is the level of correspondence between genders in these two languages? That is, do the same words use the same genders? If so, this would be useful to know for a learner of one or both of these languages.

Answer (score 2):

I may be two years too late, but I can tell you that the answer to your question is no. First, not all Romanian words are of direct Latin origin. If you take the Latin *hortus* (garden), which is masculine, and compare it with the Romanian *grădină* which is feminine, you will understand what I mean. *Grădină* comes from the Bugarian *градина* (feminine), though one may be easily tempted to believe it comes from the French masculine noun *jardin* (related to the Latin *hortus*).

However, *manus* (Latin) and mână (Rom) are both feminine. *Caput* and *cap* are both neuter. Whereas *pedes* (Latin) is masculine and *picior* (Rom) is neuter.

I would think, therefore, that your premise does not stand. Better take each language on its own. One thing Latin could help you with in learning Romanian is recognising the roots and some patterns of inflections. Not an easy language to learn I must say. I tried to teach it to an English person and I was dumbfounded how complicated the grammar is... But, do not despair, it has its logic. Once you find it, you'll be fine.